# discord bot (python) how to use wait_for to wait for a message or a reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a sort of trivia command for my discord bot where users get a random word with letters missing and they have to guess what that word is in order to win.

However I'd also like to have a reaction placed on the bot's trivia message which users can press to instantly reveal what the word is so they can then type it down and win.

What I'm basically looking for is a way to use the wait_for coroutine to wait for a reaction which will reveal the word and a message which will prompt the winner. (the use of the reaction would be optional so it's not always guaranteed to be used over just guessing the word).

Here's what I have so far.

```
        wordChosen = random.choice(randomWords)

        def check(m): # Checks if the user entered the correct word.
            if m.content.lower() != wordChosen:
                return False
            elif m.channel != channel:
                return False
            else: # User met the requirements.
                return True


        try:
            msg = await self.client.wait_for(
                "message",
                timeout=60,
                check=check
            )
        except:
            asyncio.TimeoutError
            await wordMessage.edit(content=f"You guys took too long!. The word was {wordChosen}.")
        else:
            if msg:
               await msg.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention} guessed the word!")
```

Comment: Can you double-check your indentations and format them correctly? And also, you want it to wait for a message or a reaction at the same time?

Comment: yes, pretty much

Comment: Your except clause will not work and return an error btw

Comment: It does work, I tried it before hand

Comment: In the code you are showing us, it should return an error.... (`asyncio.TimeoutError` should be behind the `:`)

Comment: apologies, I must of made a mistake with formatting it on stack, however when I run it I don't get an error so that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

After the `except` part you should put `asyncio.TimeoutError`. Instead of putting it after the `:`.

Meaning it would be:

```
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await wordMessage.edit(content=f"You guys took too long!. The word was {wordChosen}.")
```